# Solving a coupled third order nonlinear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a particular system of nonlinear differential equations for some research I'm doing. I'd like to find an analytic solution, but of course this may not be possible. However, the differential equations I've found are quite simple, albeit (as the title suggests) nonlinear and third order. The equations are
\begin{align}
    y\hspace{0.1cm}\dddot{y} &= a^2(1-\dot{x}) x ,\\
    \frac{\dot{y}}{y} &= (1+ \dot{x}) \frac{1}{x},
\end{align}
for two variables $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.
The boundary conditions I'm subject to are $\dot{x}(0) = 0$, $\dot{y}(0) = 0$, $x(1)=0$, and $y(1) = 1$. The constant $a$ comes from a separation of variables I had done prior to derive this system of ODEs from a system of PDEs.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Do these equations look familiar to anyone?

Comment: The second equation gives. $\displaystyle y = cxe^{\int{\frac{dt}{x}}}$. Plugging it into the first is a mess.

Comment: Have you tried a power series in $t$ ,  $\displaystyle y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$, $\displaystyle x(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nt^n \,$?